# Storing avro data in ORC format in HDFS with out using HIVE

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, avro, orc

Am  comparing  storing avro data in to ORC and  Parquet format,
i got  success in storing Avro data into parquet using  "com.twitter" % "parquet-avro" % "1.6.0" , but unable to find any information or API to store the avro data in ORC format.

Is that ORC is tightly   coupled with Hive only ?

Thanks
subahsh

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by `"com.twitter" % "parquet-avro" % "1.6.0"`? It just looks like a dependency to me, and not a way to transform data.

Comment: Also, I haven't tested it, but I'd recommend using Pig - you can read in your data using `AvroStorage` and write it using `OrcStorage`. That way you don't need an intermediate table, and with any luck you won't have to specify columns either.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't said your using Spark, but the question is tagged it, so I assume you are.

The ORC file format is currently heavily tied to the HiveContext in Spark (and I think only available in 1.4 and up), but if you create a hive context, you should be able to write dataframes to ORC files in the same was you can with Parquet, for example:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
val df = sqlContext.read.avro(("/input/path")
df.write.format("orc").save("/path/to/use")
```

If you're readingthe avro data via the Spark dataframes API, then that's all you should need, but there's more details on the [Hortonworks blog](http://hortonworks.com/blog/bringing-orc-support-into-apache-spark/)

Comment: Thanks Ewan for the right   direction and below dependency will be  help full.  https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro